# How can I use this UTF-8 SVG string to get <svg>?

Tags: svg, utf-8, dom-to-image

I am using [domtoimage](https://github.com/tsayen/dom-to-image) to try to turn my html div into `<svg>`. The function from domtoimage returns the string:

`data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="288" height="1920"> .......... </svg>`

I can set this string as the `src` of an `<img>`, but the other plugin I'm using (jsPDF) cannot use that, it needs `<svg>`.

I figured I could strip the beginning part off and add just the `svg` tag to the document but this results in a really odd svg with "%0A" everywhere, which I cannot strip from the string.

[image]

Comment: URIs are encoded as per [RFC3986](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3986#section-2.1) - when encountering percent encodings you need to decode them (JS provides `decodeURI()` for this). In this case `%0A` equals to a byte with the value 10, equalent to LF (line feed). In other words: those are linebreaks to beautify your SVG markup.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

If this is your code; the problem is:

you are stuffing **text** into the `append` **function** which only accepts DOM nodes.

Only `.innerHTML` converts a **string** to HTML

If you feed the `append` function a string.. it will be displayed as a string.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/append

Note the documentation: *DOMString objects are inserted as equivalent Text nodes.*

Solution is to create an SVG **DOM element**

```
let svgElem = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "svg");
svgElem.innerHTML = mySvg;
$('body').append(svgElem);
```